# Why is there a delay in Spring AMQP Message dispatching from a filled Queue?

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I am using Spring AMQP in my message driven application. I noticed that there is a nearly constant delay of around 300ms between invocations of my message listener, even though I am sure that the queue is filled with messages. 
The logfile below shows this delay between `BlockingQueueConsumer.nextMessage` and `BlockingQueueConsumer.handle` with a call to `BlockingQueueConsumer.handleDelivery` from another thread in between:

```
2015-05-12 12:46:18,655 TRACE [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute Waiting for message from consumer.
2015-05-12 12:46:18,655 DEBUG [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] BlockingQueueConsumer.nextMessage Retrieving delivery for Consumer: tags=[{amq.ctag-wwui6QjS1fAnFPM7j6GIvw=my-queue}], channel=Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(mybrokerip,1), acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0
2015-05-12 12:46:18,967 DEBUG [pool-1-thread-6 ] BlockingQueueConsumer.handleDelivery Storing delivery for Consumer: tags=[{amq.ctag-wwui6QjS1fAnFPM7j6GIvw=my-queue}], channel=Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(mybrokerip,1), acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0
2015-05-12 12:46:18,967 DEBUG [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] BlockingQueueConsumer.handle Received message: (Body:'[B@18dc305(byte[186])'MessageProperties [headers={..headers..}, timestamp=Tue May 12 01:16:06 CEST 2015, messageId=143134227498011576, userId=null, appId=SPT-T-2, clusterId=null, type=HBT, correlationId=null, replyTo=null, contentType=text, contentEncoding=UTF-8, contentLength=0, deliveryMode=PERSISTENT, expiration=null, priority=null, redelivered=false, receivedExchange=incoming, receivedRoutingKey=my-queue, deliveryTag=8, messageCount=0])
2015-05-12 12:46:18,967 INFO  [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] QueueMessageHandler.onMessage Incoming
2015-05-12 12:46:18,967 INFO  [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] QueueMessageHandler.onMessage Done
2015-05-12 12:46:18,967 TRACE [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute Waiting for message from consumer.
2015-05-12 12:46:18,967 DEBUG [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] BlockingQueueConsumer.nextMessage Retrieving delivery for Consumer: tags=[{amq.ctag-wwui6QjS1fAnFPM7j6GIvw=my-queue}], channel=Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(mybrokerip,1), acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0
2015-05-12 12:46:19,280 DEBUG [pool-1-thread-7 ] BlockingQueueConsumer.handleDelivery Storing delivery for Consumer: tags=[{amq.ctag-wwui6QjS1fAnFPM7j6GIvw=my-queue}], channel=Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(mybrokerip,1), acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0
2015-05-12 12:46:19,280 DEBUG [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] BlockingQueueConsumer.handle Received message: (Body:'[B@1aaa7d8(byte[186])'MessageProperties [headers={..headers..}, timestamp=Tue May 12 01:17:08 CEST 2015, messageId=143134227498011584, userId=null, appId=SPT-T-2, clusterId=null, type=HBT, correlationId=null, replyTo=null, contentType=text, contentEncoding=UTF-8, contentLength=0, deliveryMode=PERSISTENT, expiration=null, priority=null, redelivered=false, receivedExchange=incoming, receivedRoutingKey=my-queue, deliveryTag=9, messageCount=0])
2015-05-12 12:46:19,280 INFO  [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] QueueMessageHandler.onMessage Incoming
2015-05-12 12:46:19,280 INFO  [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] QueueMessageHandler.onMessage Done
2015-05-12 12:46:19,280 TRACE [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute Waiting for message from consumer.
2015-05-12 12:46:19,280 DEBUG [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] BlockingQueueConsumer.nextMessage Retrieving delivery for Consumer: tags=[{amq.ctag-wwui6QjS1fAnFPM7j6GIvw=my-queue}], channel=Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(mybrokerip,1), acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0
2015-05-12 12:46:19,577 DEBUG [pool-1-thread-3 ] BlockingQueueConsumer.handleDelivery Storing delivery for Consumer: tags=[{amq.ctag-wwui6QjS1fAnFPM7j6GIvw=my-queue}], channel=Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(mybrokerip,1), acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0
2015-05-12 12:46:19,577 DEBUG [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] BlockingQueueConsumer.handle Received message: (Body:'[B@1c893d2(byte[186])'MessageProperties [headers={..headers..}, timestamp=Tue May 12 01:18:07 CEST 2015, messageId=143134227498011592, userId=null, appId=SPT-T-2, clusterId=null, type=HBT, correlationId=null, replyTo=null, contentType=text, contentEncoding=UTF-8, contentLength=0, deliveryMode=PERSISTENT, expiration=null, priority=null, redelivered=false, receivedExchange=incoming, receivedRoutingKey=my-queue, deliveryTag=10, messageCount=0])
2015-05-12 12:46:19,577 INFO  [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] QueueMessageHandler.onMessage Incoming
2015-05-12 12:46:19,577 INFO  [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] QueueMessageHandler.onMessage Done
```

The logfile shows the message processing when the queue is definately full of messages. The relevant parts of my Spring configuration file looks like this:

```
<rabbit:connection-factory id="amqpConnectionFactory" connection-factory="clientConnectionFactory"
    host="${amqp.broker.ip}"
    port="${amqp.broker.port}"
    virtual-host="${amqp.broker.vhost}"
    username="${amqp.user}"
    password="${amqp.password}"/>

<bean id="clientConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.RabbitConnectionFactoryBean">
    <property name="useSSL" value="true" />
    <property name="sslPropertiesLocation" value="classpath:server.ini"/>
</bean>

<bean id="amqpTemplate" class="org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="amqpConnectionFactory" />
    <property name="messageConverter" ref="marshallingMessageConverter"/>
</bean>

<bean id="marshallingMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.MarshallingMessageConverter">
    <constructor-arg ref="jaxbMarshaller" />
</bean>

<oxm:jaxb2-marshaller id="jaxbMarshaller" context-path="com.my.package"/>

<rabbit:listener-container id="heartbeatListenerContainer" connection-factory="amqpConnectionFactory" auto-startup="false">
    <rabbit:listener ref="queueMessageHandler" queue-names="heartbeat-bdwh" />
</rabbit:listener-container>

<bean id="queueMessageHandler" class="com.my.package.QueueMessageHandler"/>
```

I am struggling to find the reason for this delay. As far as I understand it originates from the Spring BlockingQueueConsumer. I am not sure what is happening and why there is a call from another thread to the BlockingQueueConsumer.handleDelivery method.

Any help is greatly apprectiated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe a network issue?

The default configuration handles 1 message at a time and the next is not sent by the broker until the ack is sent.

Try increasing the `prefetch` on the listener container so the container always has a message available when the consumer thread is ready.

Take a look at a network trace (Wireshark or similar).

**EDIT:**

If you have a poor network, and can live with the increased possibility of duplicate deliveries, you can also consider increasing the `txSize` so acks are not sent for every message. Be sure to set it to something less than `prefetch`, though.

Comment: Thank you,  this was exaclty the issue! In my case, setting `AcknowledgeMode.NONE` is the best solution, but as you pointed out, what I was seeing was actually network delay. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just realize there is a risk of lost messages when using `NONE`.