# Spring AMQP Message delay

Tags: spring-amqp

My question is very similar to this one: [Why is there a delay in Spring AMQP Message dispatching from a filled Queue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30189104/why-is-there-a-delay-in-spring-amqp-message-dispatching-from-a-filled-queue)

I can see a delay between two invocations of my message listener even when the queue is filled with messages. I have put a log message with the time at the very begining of the method, the time at the end, and the time that took the method (in milliseconds):

Start - End - Time
2016-09-21T10:08:55.263; - 2016-09-21T10:08:55.278; - 15;
2016-09-21T10:08:55.356; - 2016-09-21T10:08:55.356; - 0;
2016-09-21T10:08:55.388; - 2016-09-21T10:08:55.388; - 0;
2016-09-21T10:08:55.466; - 2016-09-21T10:08:55.466; - 0;

The time processing the message is about 10 ms (in average) but I can see delays greater tan 50 ms (sometimes greater tan 100 ms).

If I change the parameter PrefetchCount of the SimpleMessageListenerContainer (for example to 200), then the performance increase considerabily, and now I can see in the logs that the delay has desapear:

Start - End - Time
2016-09-21T10:26:27.336; - 2016-09-21T10:26:27.336; - 0;
2016-09-21T10:26:27.336; - 2016-09-21T10:26:27.351; - 15;
2016-09-21T10:26:27.351; - 2016-09-21T10:26:27.351; - 0;
2016-09-21T10:26:27.351; - 2016-09-21T10:26:27.351; - 0;

My questions are:

- What casues this delay? Is really Network delay? How can I prove this?
- I’ve seen in the documentation about “prefetchCount” : “The higher this is the faster the messages can be delivered, but the higher the risk of non-sequential processing.” What that really mean? If I need to process the messages in sequential order, can I have “prefetchCount” in a value more tan 1?

My configuration is like this:

```
    @Bean   
    public MessageListenerAdapter broadcastMessageListenerAdapter() {
       return new MessageListenerAdapter(myHandlerBroadcast(), "onMessage");
    }

@Bean(name="myBroadcastMessageListenerContainer") 
public SimpleMessageListenerContainer myBroadcastMessageListenerContainer() 
{
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer(myConnectionFactory());
    container.setQueueNames(PX_BROADCAST_QUEUE + environment.getProperty("my.user"));
    container.setMessageListener(broadcastMessageListenerAdapter());
    container.setAcknowledgeMode(AcknowledgeMode.AUTO);
    container.setMessageConverter(myMessageConverter());
    container.setConcurrentConsumers(1);
    container.setAutoStartup(false);
    container.setPrefetchCount(500);        // ¿1?
    return container;
 }

@Bean(name="myHandlerBroadcast")
public MyHandlerBroadcast myHandlerBroadcast(){
  return new MyHandlerBroadcast();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes; it's network. You can "prove" it by using a network monitor. By default `prefetchCount` is 1 which means the broker only allows one un-acked message at the consumer. Only when that message is ack'd is the next one sent.

Increasing the prefetch count dramatically increases performance but can cause out-of-order delivery.

> What that really mean?

Consider a prefetch count of 10. You process 5 messages and then have a failure (#6) and the message is rejected and requeued (if so configured).

Message #6 will be redelivered when you have consumed all your prefetched messages - hence it will be out of order.

If you never requeue messages then there is no problem with message delivery order.

Comment: Thank you Gary. And what about AcknowledgeMode.NONE? Should be better than have a really big **prefetchCount**?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "really big" but, yes, it should be reasonably large. We don't set the `basicQos` when using `NONE` so the broker will send messages as fast as possible. With versions before 1.3.0 this could cause an out of memory situation if the listener can't keep up. With 1.3.0 and later, we use the `prefetchCount` to keep that number of messages ready and block deliveries if the listener can't keep up.

Comment: Understand, though that you will lose any prefetched messages with that mode if the server goes down. You can use ackmode AUTO with `txSize=100` to only send an ack every 100 messages. You can get duplicates in that case, though.